# How to make a phone call from a service and display status in notification bar?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am developing an application in which when i click a number in activity, it should make a phone call but should not hide my activity. I want to make the call in background and display that in notification bar. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i found the solution but not by service. We have to extend "PhoneStateListener" and need to start Activity inside "TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING" it worked, the call is displaying notification bar and not going to call opening screen.

Answer (score 0):

[Check this conversation to see what is possible and not possible when it comes to Calling](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/wM_KJBm-2AY)

According to this conversation a call cannot be made without the call screen opening on top of your activity.